# Multiple "OR" variables in SqlCommand

Tags: asp.net, sqlcommand

The database table has the following fields: `UserName` and `FavColour`. Basically, it stores the favourite colour of each user.

Instead of using concatenation, I use `SqlCommand` to store the information in my `DataSet`. It's easy when I've got 1 variable (like this):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Colour WHERE FavColour = @favcol";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@favcol", colourVar);
```

Now, I have a checkbox selection where I can choose the colour(s) for the WHERE clause. Say I've selected blue, pink, orange, and purple this time. How would I accomplish this using SqlCommand?
(Note: The number of colours selected could vary each time)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass *multiple* parameters of the *same* "type" to SQL Server, the "most-correct" way to do it is using [table-valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx).

If you're not on a version of SQL Server that supports these, the next best way is to pass an XML document and use the XML functions in SQL Server to shred these back into a [row-set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms188282%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

The worst way you can do it is to pass a comma separated string and then have to split that back apart in SQL.

---

I can't decide where looping in C# and just adding as many parameters as necessary fits into the above. For a simple query such as the one shown, it may fit as the simplest option. I.e. the code would look something like:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
int i = 1;
var parms = new List<string>();
foreach(var colourVar = /* Obtain selected colours one at a time */)
{
    var parmName = "@favcol" + i.ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(parmName, colourVar);
    parms.Add(parmName);
}
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Colour WHERE FavColour IN (" + string.Join(",",parms) + ")";
```

This wouldn't work if/when the literal query was replaced with a stored procedure, but for a small number of possible selections, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward and efficient way is to build your query.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = String.Format(
    "SELECT * FROM Colour WHERE FavColour IN ({0})"
    , String.Join(",", MyColors.Select(c => String.Format("'{0}'", c.Replace("'", "''"))).ToArray())
);
```